# Modifying Constructors

Tags: java, constructor, account, bank

I have an assignment that requires me to modify constructors. The instruction is:

Modify both Account constructors 
First constructor will accept account number as a parameter and set account number property  (class variable)
Second constructor will accept account number and initial account balance and set corresponding properties

What I do not understand is "set account number property" and "set corresponding properties."

My two constructors are:

```
public Account(String newAccountType, double depositAmount, long accountNumber) {
    this.accountType = newAccountType;
    Random randomGenerator = new Random(); // Random Number Generator for account             number creation                           
    this.accountNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000);                                
    setAccountStatus("Active"); // call account status setter to set the status to active
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");                                                                    
    Date date = new Date(); 
    this.dateOpened = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    this.lastTransaction = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    deposit(depositAmount);
    System.out.println("Account successfully opened! Your current balance is: " + this.accountBalance);
}
```

and

```
public void deposit(double depositAmount, long accountNumber, int initialAccountNum, double accountBalance) {
    if (this.accountStatus == "Active") {
        this.accountBalance = this.accountBalance + depositAmount;
        System.out.println("Deposit successful");
        System.out.println("Balance: " + this.accountBalance);
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        this.lastTransaction = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Account is inactive");
    }
}
```

I added the accountNumber into the first and second constructors already. What is the correct way to complete this task? Thanks

Comment: Your second method is not a constructor. Ostensibly (if your assignment makes any sense) there should be another function called `Account` with a different parameter list from the first; this is another constructor. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: You should read up what a "class variable" is, then you should be able to complete this step.

Comment: To that end: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: *hint* What are you doing with your new parameters?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look at those websites. I am obviously not great with this subject. @Behe if I'm reading the assignment right I'm making an ArrayList to store account owners. Does that relate?